# Android RecyclerView smooth scroll to view that's animating their height

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-recyclerview, android-scroll

I have a RecyclerView with Expandable Child Views, when the child ViewGroup is clicked it inflates an amount of views animating the ViewGroup height from 0 to the measured viewgroup height, like the following gif:

[image: example]

The problem is: I'm calling smoothScrollToPosition on recyclerView, it smooth scroll to the view position, but it considers the current view height, which is still not expanded, in the above gif i'm touching on the under view of the recyclerview, which dont scroll to position because the view is already visible, but when i touch again (calling the smoothscrolltoposition again) it scroll the view to the correct position, because the view is already expanded.

Is there any approach to scroll the view to the top of screen or just scroll to make content visible?

For references:
This is the method called to inflate the views:

```
collapsible_content.removeAllViews();
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        View link_view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item_timeline_step_link, collapsible_content, false);
        TextView text = (TextView) link_view.findViewById(R.id.step_link_text);
        text.setText("Test");
        collapsible_content.addView(link_view);
    }
```

And this is my method to expand:

```
public void toggle() {
        collapsible_content.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        Animation a;
        if (mExpanded) {
            a = new ExpandAnimation(collapsible_content.getLayoutParams().height, 0);
        } else {
            a = new ExpandAnimation(collapsible_content.getLayoutParams().height, getMeasuredHeight());
        }
        a.setDuration(mAnimationDuration);
        collapsible_content.startAnimation(a);
        mExpanded = !mExpanded;
    }
```

And the animation:

```
private class ExpandAnimation extends Animation {
        private final int mStartHeight;
        private final int mDeltaHeight;

        public ExpandAnimation(int startHeight, int endHeight) {
            mStartHeight = startHeight;
            mDeltaHeight = endHeight - startHeight;
        }

        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime,
                                           Transformation t) {
            final int newHeight = (int) (mStartHeight + mDeltaHeight *
                    interpolatedTime);
            collapsible_content getLayoutParams().height = newHeight;

            if (newHeight <= 0) {
                collapsible_content setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                collapsible_content setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            collapsible_content requestLayout();
        }


        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My solution was to constant check for view bottom within applyTransformation method, and compare it with RecyclerView height, if the bottom get higher than the RV height, i scroll by the diff values:

```
final int bottom = collapsible_content.getBottom();
final int listViewHeight = mRecyclerView.getHeight();
if (bottom > listViewHeight) {
    final int top = collapsible_content.getTop();
    if (top > 0) {
        mRecyclerView.smoothScrollBy(0, Math.min(bottom - listViewHeight + mRecyclerView.getPaddingBottom(), top));
    }
}
```

The trick was to use Math.min to get the view top, so it don't scroll up making the top not visible.

Solution based on [ListViewAnimations](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations)

Answer (score 0):

Add an animationlistener and start the scrolling of the recyclerview after the expanding animation is finished.

Comment: I did this, but i want to scroll while the view is animating, my approach was to add an animation listener to check if the bottom Y of the view is out of the RecyclerView, then call smoothscrollby giving the value of the pixels out, but i didnt manage how to this

Comment: Okay so you want bith animations parallely

Comment: I think you have to "fake" the height of the view to pretend an higher view

Comment: What you means with fake the height of the view?

Comment: Maybe give the view a fixed height instead of the wrap_content when it is expanded