# How to move the n-th invisible item of recyclerview to center

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using a recyclerView to support an item selection function for an android app, where each item of recyclerView will be a same sized image view. When creating the recyclerView, I already know that the n-th item is the selected one, how do I directly display the n-th item in center or just make it visible?

UPDATE:
So I achieved this by first calling linearLayout.scrollToPosition(n-th position) to make the item visible, then adding a addOnGlobalLayoutListener, which will wait for the layout to be complete, then calculate the offset and do a smooth scroll to center.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26875061/scroll-recyclerview-to-show-selected-item-on-top.

Comment: this works for me [Scroll to nth item ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31235183/recyclerview-how-to-smooth-scroll-to-top-of-item-on-a-certain-position)

Comment: Hi please check this answer .It works for me [] [Scroll to nth item ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31235183/recyclerview-how-to-smooth-scroll-to-top-of-item-on-a-certain-position)

Comment: layoutmanager.scrollToPositionWithOffset helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use `layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(n-th position, half width of screen)`.
It automatically scroll to n-th item position.

Comment: Thanks! This do work to move the n-th item to visible, but still not in the center.. I guess I'll do more digging from here. :)

Comment: Though `half width of screen` makes n-th item to almost center, but you need to calculate exact center values anyway. @december