# LinearLayoutManager's scrollToPositionWithOffset with smooth animation?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

I'm working with a RecyclerView and I want the clicked item to be scrolled to the top of the RecyclerView. I tried the smooth scrolling methods from RecyclerView but none of them work as I expect.

The only one working is scrollToPositionWithOffset from LinearLayoutManager, but there is no smooth animation: item jumps directly to the top.

Is there any way to achieve a smooth animation for this scrollToPositionWithOffset method?

Comment: use `smoothScrollToPosition` method .

Comment: It doesn't work as I want. It doesn't scroll the clicked item all the way to the top

Comment: smoothScrollToPosition as well as scrollToPosition only make the item visible, but they don't position it at the top. Any suggestion? Looking at the source code does not help much :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RecyclerView - How to smooth scroll to top of item on a certain position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31235183/recyclerview-how-to-smooth-scroll-to-top-of-item-on-a-certain-position)