# How does RecyclerView smooth to the specified position with offset height?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

request ： specified position with offset height

like this:

```
val layoutManager =recyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager
layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(position, -offsetRelativeHeight)
```

can't slide smoothly 
how to solve this question？

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43505830/9060113

Comment: have you tried this yet recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position); ?