# Always item at top offset while scrollbar dragging(Fast Scrolling) with Vertical RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-room, fastscroll, android-paging-library

I want to achieve fast scroll like this in my large data set RecyclerView, I'm using `com.simplecityapps:recyclerview-fastscroll` this library to fast scroll.

[image: Fast Scrolling Large Data Set]

Item at top offset, this is what i want to do while fast scrolling.

This can do scroll at top: `scrollToPositionWithOffset(position, 0)`, but it is manual trigger by code.

I want this with the scrollbar.

I have tried using LinearSnapHelper, but that didn't helped with Scrollbar.

I'm using Room and Paging Library to load data lazily.

Thanks.

Comment: You can try this for smooth scrolling(https://stackoverflow.com/a/43505830/7706832).

Comment: @MaulikTogadiya startSmoothScroll() or smoothScrollToPosition() does not integrate with Scrollbar dragging.