# Recyclerview opens with the middle item and not from the top

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

This is my fragment where I have called the recycler view:

```
public class sgpa_frag extends Fragment {
    //View view;
    RecyclerView recyclerview;
    adapter_sgpa ac;


    ArrayList<POJO> sgpaArrayList;

    public sgpa_frag() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sgpa_frag, container, false);
        recyclerview= (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rc1);
        sgpaArrayList= new ArrayList<>();
        ac= new adapter_sgpa(sgpaArrayList);
        recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),RecyclerView.VERTICAL,true));
        recyclerview.setAdapter(ac);

        Fetchdata1();

        return view;
    }

    private void Fetchdata1()
    {
        dbmanager db= new dbmanager(getContext());

        Cursor cursor= db.fetch_data1();

        if (cursor!= null){

           // cursor.moveToFirst();

            while (cursor.moveToNext()){

                POJO pj= new POJO();
                pj.setSname(cursor.getString(0));
                pj.setSemester(cursor.getString(1));
                pj.setSgpa(cursor.getString(2));
                pj.setPercent(cursor.getString(3));
                pj.setSchemes(cursor.getString(4));
                sgpaArrayList.add(pj);
            }

            ac= new adapter_sgpa(sgpaArrayList);

        }


    }

}
```

This is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".drawernav.bottom_navi.recycler_view.sgpa_frag">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rc1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="60dp">
    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</FrameLayout>
```

I want my Recycler view to start displaying from the top item and not from the middle item .                                         Can anyone tell me what changes should I make in my code ? Thanks in advance                                .

I mean to say that, it is like this:

[image]

And I want it to be like this:

[image]

Comment: What does "opens with the middle item" mean? Can you include a screenshot?

Comment: is the recyclerview is inside a nestedScrollview?

Comment: @Jayanth No, it is not.

Comment: @RyanMentley check my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set layout width and height of the recyclerview to `match_parent`.

The actual reason for your issue is probably the reverseLayout of your your linear layout manager. This has the effect as scrolling down the recyclerview.

Use this instead: 
`new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false)`

Comment: Can you please try helping me with this as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60735312/how-can-i-add-a-search-bar-to-my-recyclerview/60735564?noredirect=1#comment107465829_60735564

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

to the recyclerview parent layout

Edit:

I think it is not a problem with `RecyclerView` instead if you are using a cordinator layout as root layout, try giving margin to your FrameLayout of 60

```
<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rc1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop ="60dp" //approx for toolbar height
    android:paddingBottom="60dp">
</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Comment: is your root layout is coorinator layout?

Answer (score 0):

Add this into you code

```
mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
```

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31235183/recyclerview-how-to-smooth-scroll-to-top-of-item-on-a-certain-position