# Recycler view scrollToPosition scroll item to top of screen

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, layout-manager

Hi I want to display index at top of  recyclerview  it when scrollin to it
I tried

```
Recyclerview.scrolltoPosition(index)
Recyclerview.smoothscrollToPosition(index)
Layoutmanager.scrolltoPosition(index)
```

even used custom layoutManager and no change .

Comment: Try that ,it works for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31235183/recyclerview-how-to-smooth-scroll-to-top-of-item-on-a-certain-position/43505830#43505830

Comment: I tried it not working with me